# Copying from map to a list of pointers

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdlist

I have this interesting assignment where I have a `std::map` of `CTurist` (previous class) and `unsigned` variable. Here's the code:

```
class CTurist
{
protected:
    string tName;
    int age;

public:
    CTurist() {};

    CTurist(string name, int age2)
    {
        tName = name;
        age = age2;
    }


    bool operator<(const CTurist& e) const
    {
        return age < e.age;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CTurist&& e);
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& is, CTurist&& e);
};

class CHotel:public CTurist
{
protected:

    string hName;
    int stars;
    int beds;
    map<CTurist, unsigned> Turisti;

public:
    unsigned Sum = 0;

    CHotel(){};

    CHotel(string hName2, int zvezdi, int legla)
    {
        hName = hName;
        stars = zvezdi;
        beds = legla;
    }



    int Compare()
    {
        list<CTurist*> list;

        int br=0;
        CTurist vyzrast;
        map<CTurist, unsigned>::iterator it = Turisti.begin();
        while (it != Turisti.end())
        {
            if (it->first < vyzrast)
            {
                br++;
            }
            else
            {
                list.push_back(std::move(&it->first));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I know it's quite a long one, but I thought it's best to give you all the information.

Now, the `int Compare()` function AT THE BOTTOM is the one causing me problems.

I have to check if the age of the tourists is above or below a parameter which I've called `vyzrast` here. We're comparing the `age`.  If it's below, it's quite straight forward.

If it's above though, I have to add those Tourists to a `list<CTurist*>`, aka. to a list of pointers. If I make the list from objects, not pointers. No luck with this, hence why I'm looking for suggestions how to fix it here.

Comment: "I know it's quite a long one, but I thought It's best to give you all the information" - you are correct, this is indeed unnecessarily long. Please create a much shorter example (just the bare minimum that reproduces the problem). Chances are that while doing that you might discover what is it that you need to be done ;-)

Comment: @YePhIcK: Shortened.

Comment: It is unclear why would you derive `CHotel` from a `CTourist` while you have list of tourists stored in your hotel? As for the specific question on pointers: pointers have to **point** to something (in your case - objects). You can't just have pointers without the objects they points to.

Comment: What should `list` contain? Pointers to `CTursit`s whose ages are less than `vyzrast`?

Comment: @YePhIcK That's from an different appoach from before. Thanks for noticing. Judging on what you said, I made this:
 CTurist* baba = new CTurist(it->first);

   list.push_back(std::move(baba));

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Whose age is more than vyzrast.

Comment: @TimothyY "*I made this*" - that is a memory leak waiting to happen, and it doesn't even get you what you want (pointers to the map's keys). If you are going to make copies of the keys like that, then you may as well just use `std::list<CTurist>; ... list.push_back(it->first);` instead

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using rvalue references for your `operator` overloads? You should be using `const CTurist &` for `operator<<` and `CTurist&` for `operator>>`.  And you should be using `std::istream` for `operator>>`:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CTurist &e);
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, CTurist &e);
```

Aside from that, there is no reason for `Compare()` to use `std::move()` at all when populating the `std::list`, as it is adding pointers, not moving actual objects.

`Compare()` doesn't won't correctly for several reasons:

1. `it->first` is an actual `const CTurist` object, but your `std::list` is expecting `CTurist*` pointers.  `std::map` keys are `const`, so `&it->first` is a `CTurist const *` pointer (non-const pointer to const object), not a `CTurist*` pointer (non-const pointer to non-const object) like you are expecting.
2. Your `vyzrast` object is uninitialized.  You are not assigning any value to its `age` (and `tName`) member at all, so the result of your comparisons is indeterminate.
3. You are not incrementing your `it` iterator on each loop iteration, so you are stuck in an infinite loop if the `std::map` is not empty.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int Compare()
{
    std::list<const CTurist *> clist;

    int br = 0;
    CTurist vyzrast("", SomeAgeValueHere);

    std::map<CTurist, unsigned>::iterator it = Turisti.begin();
    while (it != Turisti.end())
    {
        if (it->first < vyzrast)
        {
            br++;
        }
        else
        {
            clist.push_back(&it->first);
        }
        ++it;
    }

    // use clist as needed...

    return SomeValueHere;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GVl7pR)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the use of naked pointers is a terrible idea, especially for a novice. And that there's **never** a good reason to  have protected data members (protected member functions are quite fine and useful though)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's pretty obvious i'm a mere novice at this language and that type of help is extremely helpful. Just as a future reference, if I were to want to use a list<CTurist*> without it being a const, how would I go about it? Pointers combined with lists and maps are really dark matter to me.

Comment: @TimothyY what's wrong with using `const`? That is what the `map` is actually storing, so pointers to its keys need to match. Otherwise, you could `const_cast` the `const` away, but that is not a good idea.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry for the late response. No, nothing wrong, I'm simply asking to see if there is an option to do that, which you did indeed explain. Thanks again.