# Reading a file into a vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have given it a few tries based on what I've read on numerous forums and books I have here. More details about this assignment here with more code from it: [Click- another question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109501/copying-from-map-to-a-list-of-pointers?noredirect=1#comment87236842_50109501)

What exactly I need to do is create a file with CHotel objects and insert them in this vector  m_hoteli.

As to why it isn't working, it is either not reading the string from the file and it's not filling the vector at all.
This is my file:

> "Marina" 5 500
>
> "Tulip" 4 400
>
> "BlackSea" 3 300
>
> "SwissBell" 5 600

```
class CComplex:CHotel
{

protected:
    string m_complex;
    vector<CHotel> m_hoteli;
public:
    CComplex(){};

    CComplex(string filename, string nComplex)
    {


        fstream file("filename.txt", ios::in);
        CHotel temp(" ",0,0);
        while (file >> temp)
        {
            m_hoteli.push_back(temp);
        }
/* Second try:
m_complex = nComplex;

        fstream in;
        in.open(filename, ios::in);
        string s;
        while (getline(in, s))
        {
            CHotel h1(s);
            m_hoteli.push_back(h1);
    }

Third try:
m_complex = nComplex;
        ifstream iStream(filename);
        if (iStream.good())
        {
            copy(istream_iterator<CHotel>(iStream), istream_iterator<CHotel>(), back_inserter(m_hoteli));

            }
        }

*/


    }
```

That's the CHotel code:

```
class CHotel : public CTurist
{
protected:

    string hName;
    int stars;
    int beds;
    map<CTurist, unsigned> Turisti;

public:
    unsigned Sum = 0;
    int br = 0;
    CHotel(){};

    CHotel(string hName2, int zvezdi, int legla)
    {
        hName = hName;
        stars = zvezdi;
        beds = legla;
    }


    friend istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CHotel& e)
    {
        is >> e.hName >> e.stars >> e.beds;;

        return is;
    }
```

I just do this in the main: CComplex c1("filename.txt", "Complex1");

Comment: note that using istream>> will read your file space by space not line by line

Comment: @LorenceHernandez: Ah I see. That's why with commas it didn't work. Removed all commas and now it fills the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the filename parameter in the CComplex constructor, other than that your code should work.

```
        fstream file(filename, ios::in);
```

Do you know how to step debug?  [Here is some info on debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Here is your full code, the only change is the filename parameter and the file should now be placed in c:\temp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class CTurist
{
protected:
    string tName;
    int age;

public:
    CTurist() {};

    CTurist(string name, int age2)
    {
        tName = name;
        age = age2;
    }


    bool operator<(const CTurist& e) const
    {
        return age < e.age;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CTurist&& e);
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& is, CTurist&& e);
};

class CHotel : public CTurist
{
protected:

    string hName;
    int stars;
    int beds;
    map<CTurist, unsigned> Turisti;

public:
    unsigned Sum = 0;
    int br = 0;
    CHotel() {};

    CHotel(string hName2, int zvezdi, int legla)
    {
        hName = hName;
        stars = zvezdi;
        beds = legla;
    }


    friend istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CHotel& e)
    {
        is >> e.hName >> e.stars >> e.beds;;

        return is;
    }
};

class CComplex :CHotel
{

protected:
    string m_complex;
    vector<CHotel> m_hoteli;
public:
    CComplex() {};

    CComplex(string filename, string nComplex)
    {


        fstream file(filename, ios::in);
        CHotel temp(" ", 0, 0);
        while (file >> temp)
        {
            m_hoteli.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    CComplex c1("C:\\temp\\file.txt", "Complex1");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Try putting a breakpoint in main and step through your program with f11 and f10

Comment: By using breakpoints, fstream file(filename, ios::in); line gives me "Error reading characters of string" . 

Line 226 gives this: +  file {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0x00000000 <NULL> _Set_egptr=0x00000000 <NULL> _Pcvt=0x00000000 <NULL> ...} } std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >

At the end, the temp object doesn't obtain the objects from the file.txt therefore doesn't fill the vector with anything.